# How to pass dynamic ref to a computed property in Composition API?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, multi-select, vue-composition-api, primevue

I'm trying to write a single computed property that will match 2 reactive variables, by make it dynamic. I'm using Typescript, Vue3-Composition API and PrimeVue.

Using Prime Vue I have 2 similar MultiSelect components with this structure:

```
<MultiSelect
  v-model="selectedClients"
  :selected-items-label="itemsSelected"
  :options="clientsList"
  option-label="firstName"
  option-value="id"
/>

<MultiSelect
  v-model="selectedCars"
  :selected-items-label="itemsSelected"
  :options="carsList"
  option-label="carType"
  option-value="id"
/>
```

I want to bind selected-items-label to a computed property **itemsSelected**, something like this:

```
const itemsSelected = computed((selector: any) => {
  return selector.value.length > 1 ? "{0} items selected" : "{0} item selected";
});
```

I know I can use 2 diferent computed properties just by changing between selectedClients and selectedCars, but this seems to be redundant.

```
const accountsItemsSelected = computed(() => {
  return selectedClients.value.length > 1
    ? "{0} items selected"
    : "{0} item selected";
});
```

Can I pass a dynamic param to a computed property to achieve this with a single computed prop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [higher order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function):

```js
const counter = computed(
  () =>
    ({ length }) =>
      `${length || 'No'} item${length === 1 ? '' : 's'} selected`
)
```

Usage:

```html
<MultiSelect
  v-model="selectedClients"
  :selected-items-label="counter(selectedClients)"
  :options="clientsList"
  option-label="firstName"
  option-value="id"
/>
<MultiSelect
  v-model="selectedCars"
  :selected-items-label="counter(selectedCars)"
  :options="carsList"
  option-label="carType"
  option-value="id"
/>
```

[Demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNpVUUtuwjAQvcpTVCmOSqHZRglV1VU3vUBdFRQMRI0/sh0kZHL3jjGJYOX5vc+MQ/ZuzPI0iKzKatfazng44Qez5qqTRluPACv2C7RamsGLHUbsrZbICZRzxVWrlfPovJAODd6t3Z6XcYIF9EId/LFC+YqxWMqtYex3gT9xLtCs44tnlMVE4UQvWlL4vFGRLPv+mduUfuhBeWGpN7lhXAEs0sWAwkmUBOcisHkKt/LlgvxL5+PV8FxtmgYl3pDnqJA7ak9mNlyRg3qVbkOElBDS9FsvrvT1sVyHAOkOGMd6Rdm1mvA4vUi9E33Ds4fteAY59L4zfSIhgDa+04oAe21pPNpDp9Jdabyia93KPCPBGES9BEuaq6SREmNF9BUez7q4O2N1F7OHqYI+OZJHjrj8vHA2/gP9qr4j).

Note: In the example above, the ref passed has to have a value with `.length` (an array or a string) at all times.

If it's ever falsey (`false`, `null`, `undefined`, etc...), it will error.
To allow falsey values, change it to:

```js
const counter = computed(
  () => (r) => `${r?.length || 'No'} item${r?.length === 1 ? '' : 's'} selected`
)
```