# vue3 - dynamic ref in computed status // repeating a player n times in a table and having a play/pause button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-composition-api

on the vue3 page below I have integrated a player that shows a "play" icon when the player is stopped, and a "pause" icon when it's playing.

What I am now trying to do is to let the player repeat n-times by including it in a table.

The difficulty I have is that I currently use the "ref" of the player ("audioPlayer") below as input to the "compute", and since when I repeat the player n-times I can't hard-code the player's ref, I need to find a way how the "isPlaying" is evaluated dynamically for the audioPlayer in the respective Row.

I tried to use methods, higher-order functions (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76335210/how-to-pass-dynamic-ref-to-a-computed-property-in-composition-api)) but have not been able to figure it out.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thank you

P.s. The below example works; What is missing is sticking he player in the repeating , since there I have not been able to figure out how to compute the isPlaying correctly depending on which row I am in

```
<template>
  <div v-for="index in 3" :key="index"> 
    {{ index }}. player should go here <p></p> <!-- <<<<<<<<< The player below should be repeated here -->
    ----------------------------------
  </div>

  <div v-if="!isPlaying" class="audio__play-start"  @click.stop="this.$refs.audioPlayer.play"><q-icon name="play_circle"></q-icon></div>
  <div v-else class="audio__play-pause" @click.stop="this.$refs.audioPlayer.pause"><q-icon name="pause_circle"></q-icon></div>
  
  <div>
    <audio-player
      ref="audioPlayer"
      :audio-list="['./api/soundfiles?path=/tmp&filename=rock.mp3']"
      theme-color="black"
      :show-prev-button="false"
      :show-next-button="false"
      :show-play-button="false"
      :show-volume-button="false"
      :show-playback-rate="false"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';

export default {
  
  setup () {
    const audioPlayer =  ref(Object)
    const isPlaying = computed(() => {  
      return audioPlayer.value.isPlaying
    })

    return {
      audioPlayer,
      isPlaying
    }
  },

}
</script>
```

Comment: The [ref will be an array](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for) when used on a v-for.  You do want an "isPlaying" icon for each player, right?  Instead of a computed, use a method as it can accept parameters.  Put the isPlaying div inside the v-for and call the method with the index of the current v-for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<template>
  <div v-for="index in 3" :key="index"> 
    {{ index }}. player should go here <p></p> <!-- <<<<<<<<< The player below should be repeated here -->
    ----------------------------------
  </div>

  <div v-if="!isPlaying[index]" class="audio__play-start"  @click.stop="playerRefs[index].play(),isPlaying[index]=true"><q-icon name="play_circle"></q-icon></div>
  <div v-else class="audio__play-pause" @click.stop="playerRefs[index].pause(),isPlaying[index]=false"><q-icon name="pause_circle"></q-icon></div>
  <div>
    <audio-player
      :ref="(el)=>setPlayerRef(el, index)"
      :audio-list="['./api/soundfiles?path=/tmp&filename=rock.mp3']"
      theme-color="black"
      :show-prev-button="false"
      :show-next-button="false"
      :show-play-button="false"
      :show-volume-button="false"
      :show-playback-rate="false"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';

export default {
  
  setup () {
  const playerRefs= {}
  const setPlayerRef = (el, key) => {
     if (el) {
        playerRefs[key] = el
      }
   }

    const isPlaying = ref({1:false,2:false,3:false})
    return {
      isPlaying,
      setPlayerRef,
      playerRefs
    }
  },

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @moon and @yoduh.

Your solution works, @yoduh, but unfortunately I have additional events (such as playing on the "progress bar" that can start the playing of the file, thus using the variable "isPlaying" to track which ones are playing does not work for me.

I used the suggestion by @yoduh and solved it via a method.
Thanks again to both of you for your time and kind pointers.

*Solution for repeating elements using **v-for**:*

```
<template>
  <div v-for="index in 3" :key="index"> 
    {{ index }} ---------------------------------- <p></p> 
    {{ isPlaying(index) }}

    <p></p>
  <div v-if="!isPlaying(index)" class="audio__play-start"  @click.stop="audioPlayerRefs[index].play()"><q-icon name="play_circle"></q-icon></div>
  <div v-else class="audio__play-pause" @click.stop="audioPlayerRefs[index].pause()"><q-icon name="pause_circle"></q-icon></div>
  <div>
    <audio-player
      ref="audioPlayerRefs"
      :audio-list="['./api/soundfiles?path=/tmp&filename=rock.mp3']"
      theme-color="black" :show-prev-button="false" :show-next-button="false" :show-play-button="false" :show-volume-button="false" :show-playback-rate="false" :show-play-loading="false"
    />
  </div> </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import AudioPlayer from '@liripeng/vue-audio-player'
export default {
  
  setup () {
  const audioPlayerRefs = ref([Object])
    return {
      audioPlayerRefs
    }
  },

  methods: {
    isPlaying(index) {
      if (this.audioPlayerRefs[index] == undefined){return false}
      return this.audioPlayerRefs[index].isPlaying
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

**Update:**

Just for completeness, since I wanted to use the player inside a [quasar table](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table/), I needed to slightly change the code. Quasar seems not to return the ref of the player as an array, as the v-for would.

Hence the adaption below that solves that.
@moon - thanks for the solution you had provided, that inspired me to come up with the one below using [function refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#function-refs).

Thus both of these options workd; the one above for normal v-for cases, the one below for quasar tables.

Hope it will be helpful for somebody else.

*Solution for repeating elements using **quasar table**:*

```
<template>
  <q-table
    title="Wishes"
    :rows="[{id:10},{id:20},{id:3},{id:6},{id:8}]"
    row-key="id"
    grid
    hide-header
  >
    <template v-slot:item="props">
      <div class="q-pa-xs col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 grid-style-transition" :style="props.selected ? 'transform: scale(0.95);' : ''" >
        <q-card bordered flat :class="props.selected ? ($q.dark.isActive ? 'bg-grey-9' : 'bg-grey-2') : ''">

          <div v-if="!isPlaying(props.row.id)" class="audio__play-start"  @click.stop="audioPlayerRefs[props.row.id].play()"><q-icon name="play_circle"></q-icon></div>
          <div v-else class="audio__play-pause" @click.stop="audioPlayerRefs[props.row.id].pause()"><q-icon name="pause_circle"></q-icon></div>
          <div>
            <audio-player
              :ref="(el) =>setAudioPlayerRef(el, props.row.id)"
              :audio-list="['./api/soundfiles?path=/tmp&filename=rock.mp3']"
              theme-color="black" :show-prev-button="false" :show-next-button="false" :show-play-button="false" :show-volume-button="false" :show-playback-rate="false" :show-play-loading="false"
            /> 
          </div>
  
        </q-card>
      </div>
    </template>
  </q-table>
  <a @click="console.log(Object.keys(audioPlayerRefs).length);console.log(audioPlayerRefs)">Click me</a>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
  
  setup () {
    const audioPlayerRefs = ref({})
    const setAudioPlayerRef = (el, key) => {
      if (el) {
        audioPlayerRefs.value[key] = el
      }
    }   

    return {
      setAudioPlayerRef,
      audioPlayerRefs
    }
  },

  methods: {
    isPlaying(rowIndex) {
      if (this.audioPlayerRefs[rowIndex] == undefined){return false}
      return this.audioPlayerRefs[rowIndex].isPlaying
    }
  }
}
</script>
```